# How I can increase the Integration association limit for the Amazon Connect instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I have enabled Connect Wisdom in my AWS Connect Instance. The Connect Wisdom is enabled, now I am trying to ingest data that will be displayed in Wisdom when an agent will search there. I am following an AWS tutorial to achieve my intention. You can see the tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/ingesting-content-to-power-real-time-recommendations-and-search-with-amazon-connect-wisdom/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20AWS%20CLI%20to,the%20content%20you%20just%20uploaded)

**Problem**

Everything was going smooth but when I run the following AWS CLI command, it throws an error.

**Command**

```
aws connect create-integration-association --instance-id 84ec56489-554a-422f-babf-3288d7c8fd04 --integration-type WISDOM_ASSISTANT --integration-arn arn:aws:wisdom:us-east-1:747998786930:assistant/42d03bed-25d2-ee85-a3236-00031ef345345
```

**Error**

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the CreateIntegrationAssociation operation: Reached Integration association limit for the Amazon Connect instance.
```

Can someone please guide me? I don't know, how to solve or increase the Integration association limit for the Amazon Connect instance.